# work with OpenCV in android studio 2.2 or 2.3

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

**i instaled android studio 2.3 and NDK & other essential things .and i download android OpenCV library then i add OpenCV java library in android studio project by use of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69keQjztg6o .
now i want to add and use native OpenCV library , but i don't know How can  do it and What codes i should write  in CMakeLists.txt and build.gradle(app) ?
please guide me .**

**this is my CMakeLists.txt  :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
   set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH      
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}")
add_library(
             native-lib

             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
add_library(
         nonfree
         SHARED
         IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(
                     nonfree
                      PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libnonfree.so )

include_directories(C:/dev/sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)

add_library( lib-opencv SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(lib-opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
set_target_properties(nonfree PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libnonfree.so)

find_library(
              log-lib

              log )
target_link_libraries(
                       native-lib
                       nonfree
                       lib-opencv
                       ${log-lib} )
```

**this is my build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "hoseini.seyedali.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':openCVLibrary320')

}
```

**this is error :**

```
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```